# CSS Positioning does not work

Tags: html, css, positioning

I've been aggravated with this problem for the past 2 hours. Its unbelievable.

I am creating a simple left column with three components, header background, middle repeating white background, and bot background. For some stupid reason the middle repeating background keeps overlapping the header. It won't move down when I use "background-position".

Here's my css code:

```
.leftcolumn .block{

background-color:#FFFFFF;

background-image: url([url]http://www.trixmasta.com/softpak/images/lnav_center.png);[/url]
background-position:0px 10px;
background-repeat: repeat-y;

width:205px;
}


.leftcolumn .block .wrap {

background-image: url([url]http://www.trixmasta.com/softpak/images/lnav_header.png);[/url]
background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
width:205px;
padding-left:0px;
padding-top:10px;

}


.leftcolumn .block .bot {
background-image: url([url]http://www.trixmasta.com/softpak/images/lnav_bot.png);[/url]
background-repeat: no-repeat repeat;
background-position: 0px 51px;
}
```

My HTML:

```
        <div class="block">

            <div class="wrap">

            <div class="navigation">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Link 3</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            <span class="bot"> </span>

        </div>
```

Comment: may be you tried this, but, if you don't have any content in header, it will not show up. try adding ``height:150px;`` in your header class - ``.block`` and see what happens?

Comment: Your html code is missing the css classes, is it complete?

Comment: I think he meant to put it into a table cell.  He just didn't include the table.

Answer (score 0):

`background-position` wont't move the actual elements, it only where it starts getting the image. An example would be with a sprite image, you set a background position to get a over state then another for a hover state. You may want to try using actual positioning(i.e `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right`), or try and use margins to position it how you want. As to iamserious' comment, adding content and `display:block;` to the header would also help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/7TVkh/